# Javax persistence RollbackException hibernate exception bug

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

After doing some research on the web I found the fact that hibernate has a bug>
Hibernate let's disappear the cause of some exceptions or something ;ike that what makes me unable to solve a exception.

So I have a object I try to update with the hibernate merge() method. (persist does work correctly)

I had this problem a few times before in my project and all my solutions don't work what I found before.

I also found much similar question but all the answers for them was something with the property `noRollBackFor=Exception.class` in `@Transactional`.
This is what I want to prevent doing in my code plus it doesn't work in this case.

Database I am using: MySQL

Object I try to update:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLICATIONS", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "NAME", "CUSTOMER_ID" }) )
public class ApplicationInfo extends DomainObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5112065902722692463L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private String groupId;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "ARTIFACT_ID")
    private String artifactId;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_ID")
    private String deploymentGroupId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACT_ID")
    private String deploymentArtifactId;

    @Column(name = "APP_NODES")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "application")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Set<ApplicationNode> applicationNodes;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "application")
    @OrderBy("sortKey ASC")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Stage> stages;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "application")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<ApplicationProperty> properties;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "NEXUS_INFO_ID", nullable = true)
    private NexusInfo nexusInfo;
// Getters and setters
```

the save methoid:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public T save(T t) {
    try {
        if (t.getId() == null) {
            getEntityManager().persist(t);
        } else {
            t = getEntityManager().merge(t);
        }
        return t;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    return t;
}
```

correct me if I am anything mussing / ask me if you need more information.

DomainObject:

```
public abstract class DomainObject implements Serializable, Comparable<DomainObject> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2606953921071135629L;

    public abstract Long getId();

    public abstract void setId(Long id);

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (getId() != null) {
            return getId().hashCode();
        } else {
            return this.getClass().getCanonicalName().hashCode();
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj instanceof DomainObject) {
            DomainObject dObj = (DomainObject) obj;
            if (this.getId() != null) {
                return this.getId().equals(dObj.getId());
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int compareTo(DomainObject obj) {
        if (obj != null) {
            if (this.getId() != null && obj.getId() != null) {
                return this.getId().compareTo(obj.getId());
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The Exception:
you can ignore that it references to my applicationcontroller, that only calls my safe method

```
2016-01-29 13:16:03 ERROR ApplicationsController:58 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [nl.ciber.deploy.metadata.model.ApplicationInfo#1] are being merged. Detached: [ApplicationInfo[id=1,name=MDS,customer=nl.ciber.deploy.metadata.model.Customer@603bdce,groupId=-,artifactId=-,type=-,deploymentGroupId=-,deploymentArtifactId=-,applicationNodes=[],stages=[],properties=[],nexusInfo=<null>]]; Detached: [ApplicationInfo[id=1,name=MDS,customer=nl.ciber.deploy.metadata.model.Customer@603bdce,groupId=-,artifactId=-,type=-,deploymentGroupId=-,deploymentArtifactId=-,applicationNodes=<null>,stages=<null>,properties=<null>,nexusInfo=<null>]]
jan 29, 2016 1:16:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/mds] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly] with root cause
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:72)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.saveApplication(Unknown Source)
    at nl.ciber.deploy.metadata.controller.ApplicationsController.editapp(ApplicationsController.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: _Hibernate let's disappear the cause of some exceptions or something ;ike that what makes me unable to solve a exception_ — can you add an example of it to your question?

Comment: My guess that it is related to equals and hashcode of your entity. What is the implementation you did for that?

Comment: @Aviad I think evry thing is okay over there but I'm pretty sure I can make mistakes so I'l add my domain object in my question